# Duplication issue with bpel service in cluster environment

Tags: db2, bpel, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have a bpel process which invokes a db2 stored procedure through java to get a unique sequence number and then insert that number into one of the db2 table. This process is running in cluster environment, so sometimes it happens that two instance of the process gets the same unique sequence number and then it tries to insert duplicate values into the table resulting in fault. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, the stored procedure that is supposed to generate unique sequence numbers, does not. You'll need to rewrite that procedure or, if not possible, may be synchronize calls to it in your Java program so that two processes cannot call the procedure at the same time.

Comment: Another option is to use the built-in [`sequence`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0023175.html) type in DB2, which is guaranteed to not duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The stored procedure is using sequence type in DB2. Also due to cluster environment making synchronize calls through Java will not resolve as we have two servers where the code is and Java calls to db2 sequence will be made from both of them at same time resulting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

As @mustaccio says, if you're using a sequence it's not possible to get the same value twice, regardless of how many clients are requesting values from the sequence at the same time.

That said, there's nothing that prevents you from inserting a row into a table with a value that the sequence hasn't generated yet;  Then, when the sequence returns the value in question and you try to insert it, it will fail:

```
create table test (id int not null primary key);
create sequence s1 start with 10;

-- This will insert the value 10, which is OK.
insert into test values (nextval for s1);

-- This will insert the value 11, which is OK.
insert into test values (nextval for s1);

-- Insert a row without using sequence  (BAD!)
insert into test values (13);

-- This will insert the value 12, which is OK.
insert into test values (nextval for s1);

-- This will attempt to the value 13, which will fail because it is a "duplicate", 
-- but not because the sequence generated a duplicate.
insert into test values (nextval for s1);
```

The solution to this problem is to:

1. Ensure that processes don't insert values without using the sequence
2. If #1 is not possible, make sure that you use `alter sequence` to restart the sequence such that it won't generate a conflict.  (in the example above, `alter sequence s1 restart with 14` after performing the naughty insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the Bpel is running on clustered environmnent..

If you are using Bpel Polling, please make sure that you marked 'Distributed Polling' flag.

Distributed Polling means that when a record is read, it is locked by the reading instance. Another instance which wants to pickup the record skips locked records.